# Can/should System Center 2012 Configuration Manager be installed on an Active Directory server?

Tags: system-center, system-center-essentials

I'd like to improve the monitoring of my environment, and after experimenting with Splunk Storm, New Relic and others have decided to have a look at using the Monitoring pack in System Center 2012 Configuration Manager.

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no budget to add servers into the environment.  Its currently all-physical and has 6 boxes: 2 for AD, 2 for IIS behind a load balancer and 2 for a SQL cluster.

So far I've been able to determine that System Center Essentials 2010 by design supports installation on an AD server, but the monitoring available there doesn't look as robust.

I can't find anything supporting installation of 2012 Configuration Manager onto an AD server, nor can I find any warnings against it.

I'm well aware its probably not a great idea, but is it supported or will it cause problems?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You technically *can* install SCCM on a domain controller, but I personally am warning you against it.  It is *not* recommended.

Domain Controllers should be *only* domain controllers (with maybe some other lightweight things like DHCP, etc..)  In addition, SCCM is a large, complex, heavy application that requires a lot of resources.  You're just signing yourself up for pain if you load SCCM onto an infrastructure that wasn't properly specced for it.

I would recommend that you wait until you can afford a proper infrastructure first before diving into SCCM.  It's a very powerful product, but it's also a big investment in terms of money and learning curve.